# Rails form - search engine

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to create simple search engine but I meet some problmes. I have several search_field in my form and if either is empty should returns all objects. Otherwise when it has any content it should be selected by that content. Below is my sample form:

```
  <%= form_for :product, url: products_path, method: :get do |form| %>
    <%= form.search_field :brand %>
    <%= form.search_field :model %>
    <%= form.search_field :price_from %>
    <%= form.search_field :price_to %>
    <%= form.submit 'Submit' %>
  <% end %>
```

my model method:

```
  def self.search(search)
    where(brand: search[:brand]).where(model: search[:model]).where("price >= ?", search[:price_from]).where("price <= ?", search[:price_to])
  end
```

But the above piece of code is wrong because if I leave some field empty it is treated directly as empty string instead of ignore this field and final result is not correct.
Summary this form should work similarly to filter on online store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd could do something like this

```
def self.search(search)
    results = all
    results = results.where(brand: search[:brand]) if search[:brand]
    results = results.where(model: search[:model]) if search[:model]
    results = results.where("price >= ?", search[:price_from]) if search[:price_from]
    results = results.where("price <= ?", search[:price_to]) if search[:price_to]
    return results
end
```

Good luck.

Comment: Great Job! All I had to do was change first line to "results = results.where(brand: search[:brand]) if search[:brand]" and initialize variable as activrecord. Thanks one more time!

Comment: Hmm. Sorry about that.  I thought I'd edited it to put in a default (you may not have any params).  Adding now.